# Change the color of UILabel inside table cell when cell is tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

I have a cell with an UIImage and UILabel inside it:

[image]

I have this code for setting up its content, pretty standard stuff:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *itemCellID = @"menuItem";

    NSString *currentMenuLabel = [self.menuItemStructure objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    NSString *currentMenuIcon = [self.menuItemIcon objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]; 
    MTNLeftMenuItemCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:itemCellID];
    [cell.leftMenuItemLabel setText:currentMenuLabel];
    UIImage *icon = [UIImage imageNamed:currentMenuIcon];
    [cell.leftMenuItemIcon setImage:icon];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return cell;
}
```

Now what I want to do is change this `UILabel's` text color when the cell is tapped, sort of like `.cell .label:hover { ... }` in css. This seems rather obvious in retrospect, but the `UILabel` being the subview of the cell is what confuses me.

How can I do this?

Comment: Since you seem to use a custom `UITableViewCell`, what about over writing `setSelected:animated:`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a delegate `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method called when cell is being selected

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; //Get your cell for selected row       
   cell.leftMenuItemLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];//Configure whatever color you want
}
```

Comment: How it will work when reusing the cell? everytime when u scroll the table view, it may create a new cell. so your color won't be set.

Comment: Just change identifier to
NSString *identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell_%d_%d",indexPath.row,indexPath.section];

Comment: @Vijay-Apple-Dev.blogspot.com OP has not mentioned such requirement, that it should be kept as it is :) he just asked about assigning color on selection of the row.

Answer (score 1):

Janak Nirmal answer only take care of selection at the point. if want to make the cell label color permanently then you should keep track of the cell with indexPath or someother way.

Everytime when u scroll the table view, it may create a new cell. so your color won't be set.

So you have to compare the indexPath of selected one and change the new cell label's color.

.h

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath;
```

.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *itemCellID = @"menuItem";

    NSString *currentMenuLabel = [self.menuItemStructure objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    NSString *currentMenuIcon = [self.menuItemIcon objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    MTNLeftMenuItemCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:itemCellID];
    [cell.leftMenuItemLabel setText:currentMenuLabel];
    UIImage *icon = [UIImage imageNamed:currentMenuIcon];
    [cell.leftMenuItemIcon setImage:icon];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    if (self.selectedIndexPath && [indexPath compare:self.selectedIndexPath] == NSOrderedSame){

        [self decorateSelectedLabel:cell];
    }
    return cell;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; //Get your cell for selected row
    self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
    [self decorateSelectedLabel:cell];
}
- (void)decorateSelectedLabel:(MTNLeftMenuItemCell*)selectedCell{
    selectedCell.leftMenuItemLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];//Configure whatever color you want
}
```

If you have multiple selection on cells then have array to keep the index. Good Luck

Comment: This approach is not recommended as it will be problamatic when OP wants to store multiple rows selection color. You should store indexpath to array and than compare if it exists or not.